# How to control several speakers with arduino by SD card?

Tags: arduino

Everyone,I have a question "how to control several speakers with arduino by SD card"

I have used the "TMRpcm" library to make the speaker make a sound already.
It's success to make a sound,but, the library only have one output(5,6,11 or 46 on Mega, 9 on Uno, Nano, etc).
I want to use several outputs, in other words, it can have allowed many speakers to make sounds at the same time.
I don't know how to do that...

Comment: Have you read the source yet?

Comment: I just know it's likely that the "TMRpcm" library can't use several ouputs, I don't know whether or not it offer the function by other libaray.If any,please tell me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like it can have a 2nd track with 2nd speaker. See Multi Mode at https://github.com/TMRh20/TMRpcm/wiki/Advanced-Features

Comment: "Multi Mode" = 2 tracks over 2 speakers.

Comment: Oh!I see it!Thank you! You're right! It can control over 2 speakers.
But it's not what I need, I need to control more speakers(about 20 speakers).Although it didn't solve my problem last, in a word, thank you~

Comment: There is not even enough pins for 20 speakers on an UNO. You may be able to expand on the code, using it on a Mega. Where I doubt there is enough cpu.

Comment: I certainty used Mega. But the library didn't offer so many outputs. Just only 4 pins.So...Whatever!